# Setting up Parameters from a case statement on DB2?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a query made where I have made a case statement but I need a parameter based off the results of the case statements.

I am using DB2, can anyone advise?

```
SELECT DRIVER_ID, NAME, DRIVER.USER9 AS PHONE, 
CASE WHEN TERMINAL_NUMBER IN ('42','9','75','54','52','40','42','41','6') THEN 'EAST' 
WHEN TERMINAL_NUMBER IN ('0','8','43','48','47','2','46','50','4','5','49', '1') THEN 'WEST' 
ELSE '' END AS REGION
, DRIVER_TYPE
FROM DRIVER WHERE ACTIVE_IN_DISP = 'True' AND
<PARAMETER WOULD GO HERE>
ORDER BY TERMINAL_NUMBER
WITH UR
```

As you can see I have two results from a case East or West and I would like those to be the parameters.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a common table expression to use results of a case statement as a parameter.

Using mostly the original select statement.

```
    with MyCTE as (
SELECT DRIVER_ID, NAME, DRIVER.USER9 AS PHONE, 
    CASE WHEN TERMINAL_NUMBER IN ('42','9','75','54','52','40','42','41','6') THEN 'EAST' 
    WHEN TERMINAL_NUMBER IN ('0','8','43','48','47','2','46','50','4','5','49', '1') THEN 'WEST' 
    ELSE '' END AS REGION
    , DRIVER_TYPE
    FROM DRIVER WHERE ACTIVE_IN_DISP = 'True' 
    )
    select * from MyCTE where region = ?
```